# Laravel Get User Info Error URI must be a string or UriInterface

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, guzzle

I have problem when google get user info in production
from local it success
this my code using guzzle client:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$requestAPI = $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'query' => [
        'access_token' => request('access_token')
    ]
]);
```

response:

> "URI must be a string or UriInterface"

I'm using laravel 8 and php 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
$client = new Client();
$uri = new Uri('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo');
//Uri from GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri
$uri = Uri::withQueryValue($uri, 'access_token', request('access_token'));

$requestAPI = $client->get($uri, [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
...
```